# Descending order for list-divider in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

How may I order the `<div class="item item-divider">` in descending way, where on the top I would like to have the most recent date?

```
// index.html
...
<ion-content>
  <div ng-repeat="(date,list) in items">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                {{date}}
            </div>
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in list">
                    <h2>{{item.name}} {{item.surname}}</h2>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</ion-content>
...

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// app.js

angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.items = {
     '11/12/2014':[
       {name:'mark',surname:'john',birth:'11/12/2014'}
     ],
     '12/12/2014':[
       {name:'tom',surname:'smith',birth:'12/12/2014'}
       {name:'carl',surname:'northon',birth:'12/12/2014'}
     ]
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not sort the object itself, before passing it to angular.

```
function sortObjectByKeys(object, order) {
    var sortedObject = {}, key, tempKeyArray = [];

    for (key in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            tempKeyArray.push(key);
        }
    }

    // You can also retrieve all the keys using Object.keys() method and then sort them..

    tempKeyArray.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});

    for (key = 0; key < tempKeyArray.length; key++) {
        sortedObject[tempKeyArray[key]] = object[tempKeyArray[key]];
    }

    return sortedObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the data-structure to have two keys, `'date'` and `'people'`? Then you could do
`items | orderBy:'date'`

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
$scope.mysort = function(obj){

    var sortedObject = {}, key, tempKeyArray = [];

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            tempKeyArray.push(key);
        }
    }
    tempKeyArray.sort(function(a, b){
        var parts = a.split("/");
        a = new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0])
        parts = b.split("/");
        b = new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
        return b-a;
    });

    for (key = 0; key < tempKeyArray.length; key++) {
        sortedObject[tempKeyArray[key]] = obj[tempKeyArray[key]];
    }
    return sortedObject;
}
```